# Many-To-Many Relationship from one Table in MySQL

Tags: mysql, many-to-many

I have a table with projects in it and each one has a number to identify the project uniquely.
I want to make a many-to-many table to link projects together and this will be done by the user through a GUI. This table would have columns project_id_1 and project_id_2. I wonder what the most efficient way to query the table would be if there are many projects randomly linked together
I could have something like :

| id1 | id2 |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 |
| 3 | 4 |
| 5 | 6 |
| 2 | 6 |
| 4 | 5 |

In this case all the projects are linked together.
But trying to query this seems impossible without looking through the whole table.

Does anyone have an idea how this could be done better?

Thanks

Comment: Depends on what exactly you will query. Is it all the projects that a particular project is related to? Or something else?

Comment: Yes that is correct. I want to be able to use any project that is linked to other projects and find a list of all the project linked to it and all the projects linked to those projects and so on. So if I looked for id1 = 1 above, the output here would be 1,2,3,4,5,6.

Comment: So you want to create a tree structure basically? When you have a top-project, with all the children projects that that project has, and then all the children of that children and so on..?

Comment: Sort of. But I think it is more comlicated than that. In this case for example there is no root. You can pick any number to start and take a linear path to cover all the numbers. But it could also be that many projects are linked to one number. In the end, if any relationship exists between projects, even through another project they should be in the results.

Answer (score 0):

So in the end I didn't find any MySQL black magic. I just used java and multiple queries.
It would have been nice to find a more elegant solution though. I can't be the only one faced with such a case.